# If open a remote Access database from VBA code, why does it become visible for a second when quit that instance?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I use code like this

```
Dim AccApp as Access.Application

Set AccApp = New Access.Application
AccApp.OpenCurrentDatabase (Access file to open here)
AccApp.Visible = False
```

(do stuff)

at the end I clean up:

`AccApp.Quit`  ' at this line the Access application become visible for a split second then it closes. Any way around this? I don't want to confuse users when they see an instance of Access pop open and then close.

Comment: Maybe try setting the access window to minimised as well when it's first opened?

Comment: How would you minimize that instance?

Comment: This should point you in the right direction ... https://www.devhut.net/2011/02/15/ms-access-vba-minimizemaximize-access-application/

Comment: Appreciate the help, but that looks too involved to bother with in this case; it only appears for a moment, and I don't want to put a lot of extra code in for that. I was hoping there might be a simple way to add something like AccApp.Minimize or DoCmd.RunCommand acMinimize "Specify something here" that would be a quick way to minimize it.

Comment: You have two options ... Either find some property/method of the access.application that you can use to minimise it, or use an imported API function to do the same thing. Whilst it might seem too involved, all you're really doing is identifying the window you need to minimise, and then minimising it! And if you the API route, a while new world of capabilities will suddenly become obvious. I'd ask another question ... How can I minimise an application window using Windows API calls?

Comment: Have you  tried using `OpenDatabase` method instead. It gives you the ability to open a database and keep it in storage. Ordinary users of Access may not see this database as it should be visible only to your project.